# Is there a way using machine learning to derive tags corresponding to a paragraph?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tags, dataset

I am very new to machine learning and genuinely what I am looking here is for some direction. I have a dataset which has the following columns:

1. Name
2. Description of the company
3. Category it belongs to (tag)

eg `Netflix | Netflix is an online platform that enables users to watch TV shows and movies on smart TVs, PCs, Macs, mobiles, tablets, and so on.  | Digital Entertainment, Media and Entertainment, TV, Video, Video Streaming`

I have thousands of such data about various companies. Is there a way to use this dataset to automatically generate tags when a new company name and company description is added?

I would really appreciate the name of the concept or some direction here.

Answer (score 0):

You want a tag (analogue to industry classification) right? For the latest technology, you would train (or called fine-tune) a transformer model (start with distilbert and move on to a stronger model like DeBERTa) to predict the tag using the description text. Take a look at the text classification example here (https://huggingface.co/transformers/examples.html)

It will not generate new tags, this simply classify new company into existing categories, if that's something you want